# Unity 2D drop weapons on the ground not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used this code for dropping the active gun

```
weapons = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Weapons");
activeGunDir = weapons.transform.position;

            int children = weapons.transform.childCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < children; ++i)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                {

                    activeGun = weapons.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;


                if (activeGun.activeInHierarchy)
                    {   

                    switch (activeGun.name)
                        {
                            case "Pistol":
                                GameObject aa = Instantiate(pistol_prefab, activeGunDir, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                                aa.name = aa.name.Replace("(Clone)", "");
                            break;
                            case "Uzi":
                                GameObject ab = Instantiate(uzi_prefab, activeGunDir, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                                ab.name = ab.name.Replace("(Clone)", "");
                            break;
                        }

                    weapons.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    goToNext = true;
                    }
```

weapons is an empty GameObject where I store guns. 
This is kinda work, but.. Not really. If uzi is active and switch with pistol it will drop a uzi, but if I try to do that again (switch pistol with uzi) will clone both (uzi and pistol). I can't find the issue and I think it's a easy fix but I'm stupid (I.m new in this). 
Is this happend because after this code, in the same for is the pick up method ? 
(Pick up method)

```
                    if (goToNext)
                    {

                    switch (gameObject.name)
                    {
                        case "Uzi":
                                weapons.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive(true);
                                goToNext = false;
                                Destroy(gameObject);
                                break;
                        case "Pistol":
                                weapons.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
                                goToNext = false;
                                Destroy(gameObject);
                            break;
                    }
                    }
```

And everything is in OnTriggerStay2D

Comment: Could be that FindGameObjectWithTag doesn't work with inactive game objects.

Comment: that empty gameobject (Weapons) it's always active. His children doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `activeGun.activeInHierarchy`? `activeInHierarchy` tells you if a game object is active in editor
 
If it's there to check Weapon Activation, change it to `activeGun.activeSelf`.

Comment: Same result. I already tried that. I used activeInHierarchy because I tried everything I knew.